# HP Pavilion dv5201 running 12.04 LTS 32 bit will not connect wirelessly. No problem connecting with Ethernet

Tags: 12.04

Trialling Ubuntu 12.04LTS from dvd on a HP Pavilion dv5201 laptop. I can get internet via ethernet connection to my router, but not wirelessly. The drop down menus ask questions I cannot answer, such as BSSID etc etc. I also cannot see any network displayed to which I might connect.  I am NOT a computer programmer, so simple answers if possible please.
Gordon Thompson

Answer (score 0):

did you have the wireless function enabled on the router?
What kind of protection is enabled when you check the configuration page of the wireless network on the router ?

just simple question to understand where is the problem.